# Arm assembly language rotate right with register

Tags: assembly, arm

Can anyone help me explain this code. I don't understand these codes. Specially What does it mean? **rotate R0 by R2 register**. I tried to understand but i didn't get it.

The question is:

Provide R0, R1, R2 contents after running the following code segment.

This is my code:

```
MOV R0, #0x0000FF00
MOV R2, #0xFF
MOV R1, R0, ROR R2
BIC R0, R1, R0
ADD R0, R0, R2
```

---

The result will goes here.

```
R0=........,
R1=.........., 
R2= ..........
```

How arm shift works?

Comment: I will confess to not actually being familiar with ARM's assembly-language syntax, but I'm still pretty confident that your code is invalid. `ROR` is a separate instruction. It can't be an operand to `MOV`. Also, you might be interested in [reading the fine manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/BABEHCFA.html), where it says that *"ROR can only be used with a register-controlled shift."*, and then goes on to explain what register-controlled shifts are just below that.

Comment: @CodyGray: `ror` can certainly be applied to a `mov` in ARM mode (see section _4.5.2 Shifts_ in ARM DDI 0029E). In thumb mode it's a different story.

Comment: As for the original question, ARM DDI0029E also describes explicitly what will happen when you do a register-specified ROR with a shift amount >= 32: _"ROR by n where n is greater than 32 will give the same result and carry out as ROR by n-32; therefore repeatedly subtract 32 from n until the amount is in the range 1 to 32 and see above."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a `MOV` instruction with a flexible second operand. `R0` gets rotated right `x` bits where `x` is stored in `R2`.

For an example, assume

```
r0 = 0x01
r2 = 0x02
r1 = 0x00
```

After the instruction `MOV r1, r0, ROR R2`
`R1` will equal 0x40000000 as that is 0x01 rotated right by two bits, the other registers will remain unchanged.

Comment: Why two bits? Can you explain me plz.

Comment: Because in my example, the value in r2 was 2.

Comment: If my r2 value is 0xFF, how many bits I have to rotate? Thanks.

Comment: 0xFF is a hex representation of 255, as @Michael commented on your original question, while the value is greater than 32, then 32 will be taken from it, so you would rotate by `255 % 32`